# cant access observium web interface

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, observium

I installed observium network monitoring on an ubuntu 14.04 vm the other day and I am trying to access the web interface usin the IP in the web browser.  When I do so, I an directed to the standard apache "it works" page, in the /var/www directory, and not to the observium index.php.  However, when I look in the default site file in apache (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`) it seems to be configured properly like such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /opt/observium/html
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /opt/observium/html/>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

Would there be something else I would need to change to redirect by default to the observium directory? Any help would be greatly appreciated.